# Labels collide Xcode Storyboard

Tags: swift, storyboard, constraints

I have 2 labels that I want to add to my View, but after setting constraints they collide and I can't fix it.

[image: Storyboard]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell iOS what to do between the labels. You have told it where to position the labels in the view but you haven't told it how to handle the space between them.

Add a constraint in between the two labels (from trailing of one <-> to leading of the other)

And tell it what minimum space to have there.

Or, alternatively, use StackViews and it will make your life easier.

Comment: even tho it says avoid comments like "thanks", but this really helped me, thank you.

Comment: @Iven99 no worries. Make sure to up vote/accept answers if they solve your problem. It helps you to give back to the community :D